# How to read a segment of rows from one file in R?

Tags: r, histogram, readfile

I've been trying unsuccessfully to make a histogram of just one part of data. I know how to choose the column with the $ sign, but I can't figure out how to select only certain rows. I've realized that perhaps the problem needs to be solved be only reading select columns in the first place.

So for example, my data looks something like this:

```
   Frequency Prime_type     RT
 1      high      prime    450
 2      high      prime    460
 3       med      prime    520
 4       med      prime    430
 5       low      prime    450
 6       low      prime    420
```

I want to make separate histograms for "high", "med", and "low", while using the integers in RT. Am I on the right track, is there a way to only read the "high" rows, and if so, how can I do this? Thank you.

Comment: `yourData[yourData$Prime_type == 'high',]` will give the 'high` subset

Comment: take a look at `?"["`

Comment: this doesn't seem to work. First, I want RT, so I'm originally doing: hist(data1$RT). Then, just want the 'high', so whether I do data1[data1$RT == 'high'], which just says 'data frame with 0 columns and 300 rows, or whether I try something like hist(data1[data1$RT == 'high'), I get and error. For second one, the error is Error in hist.default(data1[data1$RT == "high"]) : 'x' must be numeric

Comment: It's not `RT == 'high'`. The column woth high/low values is Frequency, so it's `Frequency == 'high'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
highData <- yourData[yourData$Freqeuncy == 'high',]
```

or

```
highData <- subset(yourData, Frequency == "high")
```

Now when you look at RT `highData$RT`, all you will get are cases in your original data object that are labelled as high. Repeat with medium and low to obtain those data.

Comment: it looks like that worked, thank you! I'm new to R and spend hours searching for an answer in different tutorials, and I read the sections about histograms and read file carefully but to no avail. I also tried using R's help function. What's the name for the brackets you used, [ ] ? Or is there a way I can search for a solution to a similar problem in the future? Thanks again.

Comment: It's a way of selecting data, the term to look it up is probably "subset" or "subsetting". The format for the first example is `[rows, columns]`. So what I did was selected all rows where column `Frequency` was equal to "high".

Comment: @PeterWilliams to get help for special characters, use quotes around them. In this case, try ?"["

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
with(data[data$Frequency=="high",], hist(RT))
```

Then repeat for other groups by substituting "medium" and "low" in the appropriate spot.

If you want to do them all in one go in `ggplot2`, you could use:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(x=RT)) + geom_histogram() + facet_grid(Frequency ~ .)
```